# Replace null with empty string when writing Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, null

Is there a way to replace `null` values in a column with empty string when writing spark dataframe to file?

Sample data:

```
+----------------+------------------+
|   UNIQUE_MEM_ID|              DATE|
+----------------+------------------+
|            1156|              null|
|            3787|        2016-07-05|
|            1156|              null|
|            5064|              null|
|            5832|              null|
|            3787|              null|
|            5506|              null|
|            7538|              null|
|            7436|              null|
|            5091|              null|
|            8673|              null|
|            2631|              null|
|            8561|              null|
|            3516|              null|
|            1156|              null|
|            5832|              null|
|            2631|        2016-07-07|
```

Comment: I think @shu answer will be quicker than mine. you can crosscheck..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check this out. you can `when` and `otherwise`.

```
    df.show()

    #InputDF
    # +-------------+----------+
    # |UNIQUE_MEM_ID|      DATE|
    # +-------------+----------+
    # |         1156|      null|
    # |         3787|2016-07-05|
    # |         1156|      null|
    # +-------------+----------+


    df.withColumn("DATE", F.when(F.col("DATE").isNull(), '').otherwise(F.col("DATE"))).show()

    #OUTPUTDF
    # +-------------+----------+
    # |UNIQUE_MEM_ID|      DATE|
    # +-------------+----------+
    # |         1156|          |
    # |         3787|2016-07-05|
    # |         1156|          |
    # +-------------+----------+
```

To apply the above logic to all the columns of dataframe. you can use for loop and iterate through columns and fill empty string when column value is null.

```
 df.select( *[ F.when(F.col(column).isNull(),'').otherwise(F.col(column)).alias(column) for column in df.columns]).show()
```

Comment: This works. but can we scale it on entire dtafarame without specifying each individual cols

Comment: hi, what is `F`?

Comment: @wawawa, you can import pyspark sql functions as below and alias with F

 from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Answer (score 5):

Use either `.na.fill()`,`fillna()` functions for this case.

- If you have all **`string`** columns then `df.na.fill('')` will replace all **null** with `''` on all columns.
- For **`int`** columns `df.na.fill('').na.fill(0)` replace **null** with **`0`**
- Another way would be creating a **`dict`** for the columns and replacement value `df.fillna({'col1':'replacement_value',...,'col(n)':'replacement_value(n)'})`

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------+----------+
#|UNIQUE_MEM_ID|      DATE|
#+-------------+----------+
#|         1156|      null|
#|         3787|      null|
#|         2631|2016007-07|
#+-------------+----------+
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.na.fill('').show()
df.fillna({'DATE':''}).show()
#+-------------+----------+
#|UNIQUE_MEM_ID|      DATE|
#+-------------+----------+
#|         1156|          |
#|         3787|          |
#|         2631|2016007-07|
#+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Same question @Shu, how can scale this on all df columns

Comment: @ben, if you have all string columns then `df.na.fill('')` will replace all `null` with `''` on all columns, for int columns `df.na.fill('').na.fill(0)` replace `null` with `0`.