# PySpark - Set/Drop Column for individual rows and not for all records

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I was looking to find a solution to dealing with null values in AWS DynamoDB after a glue transform. Normally with data that is null, the column just won't populate for certain fields when a query is done... but on a transform with glue the field is set to null... and therefore displays null.

I found the following script online

```
def drop_null_columns(df):
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    null_counts = (
        df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
        .collect()[0]
        .asDict()
    )
    to_drop = [k for (k, v) in null_counts.items() if v > 0]
    newdf = df.drop(*to_drop)
    return newdf
```

But this script drops all columns that even have 1 null such as the example below.

BEFORE

```
C1  | C2  | C3
------------
123 |null | 12
123 |15   | 12
123 |15   | 12
123 |12   | 12
```

AFTER

```
C1  | C3
------------
123 | 12
123 | 12
123 | 12
123 | 12
```

What I would like to have happen is have the rows where a NULL exists, to just be blank/empty.

BEFORE

```
C1  | C2  | C3
------------
123 |null | 12
123 |15   | 12
123 |15   | 12
123 |12   | 12
```

AFTER

```
C1  | C2  | C3
------------
123 |     | 12
123 |15   | 12
123 |15   | 12
123 |12   | 12
```

Comment: try `df.na.fill('')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace null with empty string when writing Spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159501/replace-null-with-empty-string-when-writing-spark-dataframe)

Comment: What is the type in question is an array or a list?

Answer (score 0):

Spark automatically infers that the `C2` field is of type `long`, so you need to specify the value of `long` type when replacing it. If it is inferred that the `C2` field is of type `string`, you can use `df.fillna('')`.

```
newdf = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: What if the type is an array or a list?

Comment: Currently```fillna``` only support ```int```, ```float```, ```boolean```, or ```string```.